# Android: How to Exclude Facebook Contacts from ContentResolver Query

Tags: android, facebook, contacts, android-contentresolver, contract

I am pulling all of the phone's contacts using this query:

```
    Cursor c = cr.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, new String[] { ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_ID, ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME, ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY }, null, null, ContactsContract.Data.LOOKUP_KEY + " ASC");
```

If the user has synced their Facebook contacts, then I get those in this query along with everything else.  However, I am already pulling the user's Facebook contacts via an asynchronous API call so I want to EXCLUDE Facebook contacts from this query to avoid duplication.

Can someone point me towards the WHERE clause(selection param) I need to include that will allow me to exclude Facebook contacts from what is returned by this query?

Thank you!

Edit: Or at the very least just a field that can be selected from the ContentResolver that will allow me to manually filter the Facebook contacts?  That would be just as good.

Answer (score 0):

Ummm, just a thought.
Maybe you can filter your query to look for contacts who have a phone number.
I assume Facebook contacts will be excluded.
I might be wrong though. Haven't tried that :)